# Does ctypes.util.find_library conform to "usual" library linking practices in Linux?

Tags: linux, linker, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

Recently I ran into a problem with the Python function [`ctypes.util.find_library`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#finding-shared-libraries). The function is used to locate shared libraries by name; for example, [CuPy](https://github.com/cupy/cupy) uses it to locate cuDNN. In my case, I had several versions of cuDNN installed, and it picked up the latest (as per the documentation). However, the contents of the directory look like this:

```
$ l /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64 | grep -i cudnn                                                                                       
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         13 Oct  3 08:21 libcudnn.so -> libcudnn.so.6*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 1000 users        17 Jul 27  2016 libcudnn.so.5 -> libcudnn.so.5.1.5*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 1000 users  79337624 Jul 27  2016 libcudnn.so.5.1.5*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         18 Oct  3 08:21 libcudnn.so.6 -> libcudnn.so.6.0.21*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 1000 users 154322864 Apr 12  2017 libcudnn.so.6.0.21*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         17 Oct  2 10:32 libcudnn.so.7 -> libcudnn.so.7.0.3*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 1000  1000 217188104 Sep 16 05:09 libcudnn.so.7.0.3*
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 users 143843808 Apr 12  2017 libcudnn_static.a
```

Even though the latest version is 7.0.3, judging from the symbolic link hierarchy, I would have expected version 6.0.21 to be picked up. My questions are:

1. Which version would the `gcc` (or `clang`) toolchain have picked up during compile-time?
2. Which version would a C/C++ executable have picked up during run-time?
3. Is there any kind of information source (an article, a man page, a book, ...) out there that contains explicitly the answers to the first two questions? I tried googling it, but nothing definitive came up.

Answer (score 1):

1. Traditionally you'd build with a command like `gcc -lcudnn`.  This would find `libcudnn.so` which points to `libcudnn.so.6` which points to `libcudnn.so.6.0.21`.  So `libcudnn.so.6.0.21` would be linked at build time.
2. Traditionally a shared library will contain a "SONAME" which indicates the ABI compatible version to be loaded at runtime.  I'm pretty sure that would be `libcudnn.so.6` in this case.  So building against `libcudnn.so.6.0.21` would give you a runtime dependency on `libcudnn.so.6` (you can verify this using `ldd myprog | grep libcudnn.so`).
3. Probably, but that's not an on-topic question for Stack Overflow ("recommending an off-site resource").

Comment: Thanks, that confirms my suspicions. However, I don't think the citing a your sources (library reference, book, etc.) to support a claim counts as "recommending an off-site resource". I have seen links to API documentations or libraries many times on SO. So please, don't keep it to yourself if you have something definitive.